# Query in Embedded document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to do a query where i can reach all banks where bank is banco1 and investments are not equal to "box".

How can i do that? I tried this query, but don't work :

db.banks.find( { "investments": { $elemMatch: { bank: "banco1", productName: {$ne:"box} } } } );

This query it's one example of many that i have tried.

Thanks.

```js
 

{
  "_id": "5d3fc8c3914297c7b9a3a9e5",
  "banco": "banco 1",

  "investimentos": [{
      "bank": "banco1",
      "risk": "Conservador",
      "expiryDate": "2021-10-04",
      "tax": "1.02",
      "discriminator": "investment",
      "productName": "LCI"
    },

    {
      "bank": "banco1",
      "risk": "Conservador",
      "expiryDate": "2020-06-24",
      "tax": "0.75",
      "discriminator": "investment",
      "productName": "Fundo DI"
    },

    {
      "bank": "banco1",
      "risk": "Conservador",
      "tax": "0.04",
      "discriminator": "investment",
      "id": "259ad8ac-57b7-4d33-8e75-46cf5c5c28e3",
      "aniversary": "30",
      "productName": "box"
    }
  }],


  {
    "_id": "5d3fcb4c914297c7b9a3a9e6",
    "banco": "banco2",
    "investimentos": [{
        "bank": "banco2",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "expiryDate": "2020-06-24",
        "tax": "0.80",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "id": "73db503f-c780-448c-a6a8-05d2837ff6ff",
        "redemptionDate": "D+1",
        "productName": "Fundo DI"
      }

      ,
      {
        "bank": "banco2",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "expiryDate": "2020-12-17",
        "tax": "0.98",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "id": "54e01515-dc7f-470f-8f00-8603c8f00686",
        "productName": "LCA"
      },

      {
        "bank": "banco2",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "expiryDate": "2021-08-05",
        "tax": "1.0",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "id": "259ad8ac-57b7-4d33-8e75-46cf5c5c28e2",
        "productName": "CDB"
      }
    }]
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to try out the proposed solution?  Have you gotten the answers you need?  If so, please mark the answer or provide feedback to the proposal so that additional information can be provided if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO Luan!

I've found that [Mongo Aggregations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) give me all of the power available in find, and so much more functionality.  So about 95% of the time, unless I'm doing a quick query, I end up going to aggregates.

The following aggregate will get you what you're looking for:

```
db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$investimentos"},
    { $match: {
        'investimentos.bank': "banco1",
        'investimentos.productName': /^(?!box$)/
    }},
])
```

The [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pipeline takes the array of embedded documents in investimentos, and creates a new document, retaining the parent fields (_id and banco), for each element withing investimentos.  You can try just `db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([{ $unwind: "$investimentos"}])` to visually see what happens.

The [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline does the same thing as the find method - you give it a list of filters to apply.  The second element uses a regex (surrounded by '/' chars) to specify that it should find everything that does not start with "box".

Comment: If you need to bring those individual documents back together in their original grouping, then add a $group pipeline after the $match pipeline in the aggregate: `{ $group: { _id: '$_id', banco: { $first: '$banco'}, investimentos: { $push: '$investimentos'} }}`